# How can I remove my anaconda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am working in Mac OS X. I have created a conda environment called `python2env`. You can see it here:

```
conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
python2env               /Users/user/anaconda/envs/python2env
..
root                  *  /Users/user/anaconda
```

I tried the following command to remove it:

```
conda env remove --name python2env

Remove all packages in environment /Users/user/anaconda/envs/python2env:

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

Then, I checked if it had been removed:

```
conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
python2env               /Users/user/anaconda/envs/python2env
..
root                  *  /Users/user/anaconda
```

but it is still there!

I tried `conda remove --name python2env --all` but to no avail. The environment is still listed.

How can I remove my Anaconda environment?

Update, on jentjr's avdvice:

```
~ conda remove --name python2env --all --debug

DEBUG conda.gateways.disk.test:prefix_is_writable(65): testing write access for prefix '/Users/user/anaconda' using path '/Users/user/anaconda/conda-meta/history'
DEBUG conda.gateways.disk.test:prefix_is_writable(65): testing write access for prefix '/Users/user/anaconda' using path '/Users/user/anaconda/conda-meta/history'

Remove all packages in environment /Users/user/anaconda/envs/python2env:

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

DEBUG conda.gateways.disk.permissions:make_writable(36): tried make writable but failed: /Users/user/anaconda/envs/python2env/static/css/img/igv_logo_letters_paths.svg
PermissionError(1, 'Operation not permitted')

~ conda remove -p /Users/user/anaconda/envs/python2env --all --debug 
DEBUG conda.gateways.disk.test:prefix_is_writable(65): testing write access for prefix '/Users/user/anaconda' using path '/Users/user/anaconda/conda-meta/history'

Remove all packages in environment /Users/user/anaconda/envs/python2env:

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

DEBUG conda.gateways.disk.permissions:make_writable(36): tried make writable but failed: /Users/user/anaconda/envs/python2env/static/css/img/igv_logo_letters_paths.svg
PermissionError(1, 'Operation not permitted')
INFO conda.gateways.disk.delete:rm_rf(59): rm_rf failed for /Users/user/anaconda/envs/python2env
```

Neither using `--debug` nor specifying the full path to the environment were able to remove it. I will try to make the environment writable with `chmod`, try again and update my post.

Comment: Did you try with `--debug`, or with the full path to the environment using `-p PATH`

Comment: Have you tried deleting file /Users/user/anaconda/envs/python2env/static/css/img/igv_logo_letters_paths.svg ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a similar issue with a `conda-meta` folder in the environment directory and solved it with `rm -rf [full-path-to-conda-env]`.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use `conda env remove -n [name]` if I want to delete the entire environment.

Comment: `-n` is the same as `--name`, so this is what OP tried, and it didn't work for them.